# meteor mobile app forgot password feature

Tags: meteor, passwords

I have built a mobile app using meteor. signUp is done using otp. I have added a forgotPassword button but not sure how to use it. 
I am verifying the user and using the below code to reset the password :
(user is not logged in)

```
 Accounts.setPassword(id, password, function(err, res){
      if(err)
        alert('try again : ' + err);
      else{
        console.log('suv : ' + res);              
      }
    });
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Have a look at https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-setPassword There is no callback function

Comment: I went through the docs. I get the following error : Uncaught TypeError: Accounts.setPassword is not a function

Comment: Have you added the accounts-password package, and are you importing Accounts to your code

Comment: I have the account-password package in my app. And no, I am not importing Accounts to my code. The code is written on the client side

Comment: I am not sure if one needs to separately import Accounts. Its already there. I am using meteor version 1.5

Comment: Now i separately included accounts. I get the following error now : Uncaught TypeError: _accountsBase.Accounts.setPassword is not a function

Comment: Okay. So I moved the code to server side and its working now. not sure why though, as I can call Accounts.createUser, Accounts.changePassword on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So I moved the code to server side and its working now. not sure why though, as I can call Accounts.createUser, Accounts.changePassword on the client side